# SwiftUI List =>EditButton => Minus, is not showing delete

Tags: listview, swiftui

When I press the edit button => minus icon, in a list view, the delete button won't show up on that particular row.

this is my code:

```
List {
    Section(header: Text("Items")) {
        ForEach(self.items, id: \.id) { item in
            HStack {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(item.name)
                 }
             }
         }   .onDelete(perform: delete)
     }
 }
 .navigationBarTitle(NSLocalizedString("Select an item", comment: "item.list.title"))
 .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was doing the closing of the keyboard when tapoutside in my appdelegate. that was causing the delete button not to appear. After removing that line of code it worked again. I have placed now the code for closing the keyboard in the view it belongs to now. Everything works fine :)